# Remi Dependency on CentOS, got error: "Failed dependencies: epel-release >= 5 is needed"

Tags: centos, centos5

Box info: CENTOS 5.8 i686 with cPanel.

I am trying to add [Remi](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/)

```
$ rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
```

Got error:

```
Retrieving http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    epel-release >= 5 is needed by remi-release-5-8.el5.remi.noarch
```

What can I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need EPEL repository as the error message indicates:

http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL

Regards